# I won't get value in array or object in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, eloquent

I already get data like this Using laravel query builder

```
[0]
    Category_id:1,
    product:food
[1]
    Category_id=1
    product:fish
[2]
   Category_id=1
   product:vegetable
```

But I want this formate

```
category_id 1{
          product
                { "Food","Fish","Vegetable"}

}
```

Comment: You need to provide sample code and form your question better. I have no idea what you are asking. What are you trying to accomplish? What is the error that is happening? Utilize code markup to make your examples readable.

Comment: Share your query builder code and the complete result data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck):

```
$collection->pluck('product')->all();
```

> The pluck method retrieves all of the values for a given key

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$collection->groupBy('category_id')
    ->map(function($item) {
        return $item->pluck('product');
    });
```